# How to create a round button with text and Image

Tags: android, xml, image, button, text

I want to make a round button with text and image like this.

[image: button1]

Until now I made this button but I cant make the round corners for the Image.

[image: button2]

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/muscle_button_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search_button_gradient"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/muscle_button_paddingRightLeft"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/muscle_button_paddingRightLeft"
    android:text="Search"
    android:textSize="@dimen/muscle_button_text_size"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

and the **drawable.xml** for the background is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#E12778"
        android:endColor="#F83E25" />

    <corners android:radius="30dp" /> 
shape/>
```

I want to make the button like this ([Image without round corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vb8u.png)) but with rounded corner image programatically or from xml.

```
layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/biceps" />
<item>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient  android:startColor="#80E12778"
            android:endColor="#80F83E25"
            />
        <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

layer-list>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want? I think your Button is corner round now .

Comment: can u post the background image you are using?

Comment: Why don't you create that image (PNG) in photoshop and use it as a source for `ImageView` with an `onClick`?

Comment: I edited the post with the actual result when I use a background Image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vb8u.png).  I don't wanna have multiple photos because of the round corners and because of that I don't use png images with round corners. Thanks

Comment: You can create an Image as the very first desired image in your post directly in Photoshop and use it as the source of an ImageView. No need of multiple images. Just create it.

Comment: Yes but I want to use the images without gradient and round corners in other places and I don't wanna have 36 different images in my resources files. If I can reuse the pictures applying  them a filter and round corners programatically will be better.

Comment: hi @L.Dan, did you find a solution for this? I have the same question/problem. How did you solve it?